# How to open or view a Microsoft document from a url in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, ios15

When I think of documents, I'm thinking about Microsoft products: Word, Excel etc and PDFs. An example, Teams for iOS, I can open a Word file in-app or download and view later.

I know Microsoft is doing some complexity behind the scenes but I wanted to view a document, an excel, from a given url. I have an S3 url to the file that I want to load/read. I do not know where to start so I've Googled "Loading excel/word file from url in swiftui". Nothing really useful shows up. What I do see is how to download and save a file but for what I'm doing, I wont be downloading anything. I came across these resources:

- [Build document-based apps in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10039/)
- [Building a Document-Based App with SwiftUI (Code)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/building_a_document-based_app_with_swiftui)

None of the above give me a clue on how to load a document file from a given url: `https://www.path-to-file.docx/xls` but will be useful later in the process.

PS: I'm building an app while learning, and to break this down, the first step is to load/view the doc/excel file in a view window, later I'll read more documentations to figure out how to make changes etc. The question, how to open a file from a url, any Microsoft products? If that's too much, how to open just one? Is there a resource I could read?

If not possible in SwiftUI, I could learn the UIKit way. Anything to get the job done.

Comment: @KJ Thanks for your input. Are you saying the only way to view a document is by downloading it first, somewhere in FileManager?

Comment: @KJ Right. I think this is a starting point. Thanks for that.